# How add many google map markers from my database?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have laravel API LAT & LNG and i want to show all markers in a map. I tried to make a loop to red it but show only one mark. How can I solve this?

```
var lat ;
var lng ;

var mylist ;
  Future<List<Post>> getData() async {
    // start get post     
      http.Response response = await http.get(
          " mysite.com/api/getall",
          headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},);
      List collection = json.decode(response.body);
       mylist = collection.map((json) => Post.fromJson(json)).toList();
     for(var i in mylist){ 
        lat = i.lat ;
        lng = i.lng ;
      }  
  } // end getData
///////////////////////////

                  FlutterMap(                      
                        options: new MapOptions(                          
                          center: new LatLng(lat, lng),
                          zoom: 12.0,
                        ),
                        layers: [
                          new TileLayerOptions(
                              urlTemplate:
                                  "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                              subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
                          new MarkerLayerOptions(markers: [
                            new Marker(
                                width: 45.0,
                                height: 45.0,
                                point: new LatLng(lat, lng),
                                builder: (context) => new Container(
                                      child: IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                        iconSize: 45.0,
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          print('Marker tapped');
                                        },
                                      ),
```

Comment: You will need to create the Markers in a loop, too. At the moment you only add one marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MarkerLayerOptions` you can actually pass a list of markers. At the moment you only have one marker in the list, so that is why you only see one marker.

So you would basically do this (not tested, you might need to adjust the syntax a bit...)

```
var mylist ;
List myMarkers = [];

Future<List<Post>> getData() async {
    // start get post     
      http.Response response = await http.get(
          " mysite.com/api/getall",
          headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},);
      List collection = json.decode(response.body);
       mylist = collection.map((json) => Post.fromJson(json)).toList();
     for(var i in mylist){ 
        lat = i.lat ;
        lng = i.lng ;
        var nextMarker = new Marker(
                            width: 45.0,
                            height: 45.0,
                            point: new LatLng(lat, lng),
                            builder: (context) => new Container(
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    iconSize: 45.0,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      print('Marker tapped');
                                    },
                                  ),
                             );
        myMarkers.add(nextMarker);
      }  
  } // end getData


  ///////////////////////////

              FlutterMap(                      
                    options: new MapOptions(                          
                      center: new LatLng(lat, lng),
                      zoom: 12.0,
                    ),
                    layers: [
                      new TileLayerOptions(
                          urlTemplate:
                              "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                          subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
                      new MarkerLayerOptions(markers: myMarkers),
                    ])
```

As stated above, do not expect that code to work out of the box, it is only here, to illustrate the general idea.

Comment: error... "type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Marker>'
"

Comment: As I said, I did not test the code... I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks ..  frankenapps .. for your help and time :)